Hello I have trouble creating a balance tracker for solana

The problem

This is the code that I am working with. It's supposed to track my wallet balances on Solana, SOL and Memecoins/SPL tokens included. The code works only partially, it writes out my SOL balance, but then prints some error messages and stops working, I haven't been able to find a solution even with ChatGPT input.
The error message is the following: c:\Users\vhrom\Desktop\Coding vol.2# List of numbers to be sorted.py:35: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
Error: expected a sequence of length 32 (got 43)
import asyncio
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
from solana.rpc.types import TokenAccountOpts
from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed

# Define the wallet address directly in the code
wallet_address = "BdL79v8z3mTnNhVfQBmtzRvL1gyw7U1vPTuJ4LKN3hpT"

# Initialize the Solana client
solana_client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

async def get_token_accounts(wallet_pubkey):
    async with AsyncClient("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com") as client:
        resp = await client.get_token_accounts_by_owner_json_parsed(
            wallet_pubkey,
            TokenAccountOpts(program_id=Pubkey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")),
            commitment=Confirmed
        )
        return resp['result']['value']

def get_wallet_balance():
    try:
        # Convert the wallet address to a Pubkey object
        wallet_pubkey = Pubkey.from_string(wallet_address)

        # Get the balance of the wallet in SOL
        balance_info = solana_client.get_balance(wallet_pubkey)
        balance_lamports = balance_info.value  # Directly access 'value' attribute
        balance_sol = balance_lamports / 1e9  # Convert lamports to SOL
        print(f"The balance of wallet {wallet_address} is {balance_sol} SOL.")
        
        # Get token accounts
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        token_accounts = loop.run_until_complete(get_token_accounts(wallet_pubkey))
        for account in token_accounts:
            token_balance = account['account']['data']['parsed']['info']['tokenAmount']['uiAmount']
            token_mint = account['account']['data']['parsed']['info']['mint']
            print(f"Token: {token_mint}, Balance: {token_balance}")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Solana Wallet Tracker!")
    # Get and print the balance of the specified wallet
    get_wallet_balance()
    print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Thank you for any help I can get.

the first message "DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()" is a DeprecationWarning , which means that this function is deprecated, you can still work with that but is better to use:
token_accounts = asyncio.run(get_token_accounts(wallet_pubkey))

The second message "Error: expected a sequence of length 32 (got 43)", it's because you are passing in get_token_accounts_by_owner_json_parsed the program id as Pubkey from a string but you have to pass it as base58 decoded.
resp = await client.get_token_accounts_by_owner_json_parsed(
        wallet_pubkey,
        TokenAccountOpts(program_id=Pubkey(base58.b58decode('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA'))),
        commitment=Confirmed
    )

The get_token_accounts_by_owner_json_parsed function return the result as "solders.rpc.responses.GetTokenAccountsByOwnerJsonParsedResp" that is not subscriptable so you have to turn it into json:
resp = resp.to_json()
resp_json = json.loads(resp)
return resp_json['result']['value']

This is the complete code:
import asyncio
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
from solana.rpc.types import TokenAccountOpts
from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
import base58
import json

# Define the wallet address directly in the code
wallet_address = "BdL79v8z3mTnNhVfQBmtzRvL1gyw7U1vPTuJ4LKN3hpT"

# Initialize the Solana client
solana_client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

async def get_token_accounts(wallet_pubkey):
    async with AsyncClient("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com") as client:
        resp = await client.get_token_accounts_by_owner_json_parsed(
            wallet_pubkey,
            TokenAccountOpts(program_id=Pubkey(base58.b58decode('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA'))),
            commitment=Confirmed
        )
        resp = resp.to_json()
        resp_json = json.loads(resp)
        return resp_json['result']['value']

def get_wallet_balance():
    try:
        # Convert the wallet address to a Pubkey object
        wallet_pubkey = Pubkey.from_string(wallet_address)

        # Get the balance of the wallet in SOL
        balance_info = solana_client.get_balance(wallet_pubkey)
        balance_lamports = balance_info.value  # Directly access 'value' attribute
        balance_sol = balance_lamports / 1e9  # Convert lamports to SOL
        print(f"The balance of wallet {wallet_address} is {balance_sol} SOL.")
        
        # Get token accounts
        token_accounts = asyncio.run(get_token_accounts(wallet_pubkey))
        for account in token_accounts:
            token_balance = account['account']['data']['parsed']['info']['tokenAmount']['uiAmount']
            token_mint = account['account']['data']['parsed']['info']['mint']
            print(f"Token: {token_mint}, Balance: {token_balance}")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Solana Wallet Tracker!")
    # Get and print the balance of the specified wallet
    get_wallet_balance()
    print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This code work for me, let me know if u have any question.

yeah that works awesome dude thanks

Please accept the answer if it worked for you, that way others can find it in the future!
